# Loading video from database and playing video faster in website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing the html5 website user's can upload there videos and also they can watch the video through my website one problem i'm facing locally video's are loading faster without buffering can watch but i uploaded in to the google cloud it's taking time to load the videos and it's more time to buffering to play the video.

through the select query i'm fetching the video like 
SELECT `video` FROM `video` i'm using mysql database.

```
<video class="embed-responsive-item"  height="500" controls controlsList="nodownload">
<source src="<?php echo $u_pvid; ?>">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

give a feedback to how can i fix this issues from website...

Answer (score 0):

you should select address of video from database not all contents.actually your video file should save in hard disk or use CDN and access them over videos address in your database.
also your internet speed specifies how fast video load and play.